# BEGINNER Trying to debug a program that uses two other modules in order to run. Can't seem to define variables

Tags: python, debugging

I am using Python IDLE. I am trying to create a Trip Planner that will look like this:

```
---------------------------
Welcome to  the Trip    Planner
---------------------------
Travel  Options
--------------
1.  Rome
2.  Berlin
3.  Vienna
Where   would   you like    to  go? 2
And how many    days    will    you be  staying in  Berlin? 5
Your    trip    to  Berlin  has been    booked!



Itinerary.txt
Trip    Itinerary
--------------
Destination:    Berlin
Length  of  stay:   5
Cost:   $100.80
```

After   running,    this    program would   have    generated   a   text    file    named   itinerary.txt. What I seem to have trouble with is the currency.py which is not working for me. Python keeps telling me to define euro_rate and when I try to a numerous amount of problems pop up and it's frustrating for me because I am just a beginner.

Here is what I have on part of the planner that might need some fixing...

```
def main():
    # Show destinations
    destinations.print_options()

    # Pick destination
    choice = destinations.get_choice()

    # Get destination info
    destination = destinations.get_info(choice)

    # Calculate currency exchange
    dollar_rate = currency.convert_dollars_to_euros(euro_rate)

    # Calculate cost
    cost = dollar_rate + length_of_stay
```

And my whole currency program looks like:

```
def convert_euros_to_dollars(euro_rate):
    return (euro_rate * 1.12)

def convert_dollars_to_euros(dollar_rate):
    return (dollar_rate / 1.12)
```

At this point I am just lost and I need a little extra help.

Answer (score 1):

Python is telling you to define `euro_rate` because `euro_rate` is undefined. You need to *define* it to be something in your `main()` function , or you need to pass it's actual value as a parameter to `convert_dollars_to_euro`. It's quite impossible for your conversion to work properly when you don't give your program a `euro_rate` to work with anywhere.

For instance, if you wanted `euro_rate` to be equal to `2.0` when you passed it to your `convert_dollars_to_euro`, you could define the variable at the beginning of your `main()` like this:

```
def main():

    #defining variables
    euro_rate = 2.0

    # Show destinations
    destinations.print_options()

    # Pick destination
    choice = destinations.get_choice()

    # Get destination info
    destination = destinations.get_info(choice)

    # Calculate currency exchange
    dollar_rate = currency.convert_dollars_to_euros(euro_rate)

    # Calculate cost
    cost = dollar_rate + length_of_stay
```